# Increasing performance when loading images from drawable

Tags: android, bitmap

I am trying to improve the performance in my app when loading 6 large images into an ImageView that are displayed in a GridView.

I know the technique I am using now is awefull.

I have looked at Android's [Loading Large Bitmaps Efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html) , but can't get my head round implementing the techniques they use into my code.

Any help would be appreciated.

Here's my class that is used to load the images into the ImageView:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class AdapterViewADV1 extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContext;



// Keep all Images in array
public Integer[] mThumbIds = {
        R.drawable.image_1,
        R.drawable.image_2,
        R.drawable.image_3,
        R.drawable.image_4,
        R.drawable.image_5,
        R.drawable.image_6

};



// Constructor
public AdapterViewADV1(Context c){
    mContext = c;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mThumbIds.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mThumbIds[position];
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView = null;
    if(convertView == null){
       imageView  = new ImageView(mContext);imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
       imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(NO_SELECTION, NO_SELECTION));
       convertView = imageView;
    }else{
        imageView = (ImageView)convertView;
    }
    imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);

    return convertView;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

USE 
[IMAGE LOADER](https://code.google.com/p/android-query/wiki/ImageLoading)  it is light weight

Comment: AQuery aq = new AQuery(activity);
  String imageUrl = "http://www.vikispot.com/z/images/vikispot/android-w.png";
  aq.id(R.id.image1).image(imageUrl, true, true, 0, R.drawable.default_image);

Answer (score 1):

You can compress your .png images without reducing transparency
 [Click Here to compress](http://tinypng.org/)

Comment: @Jack The compression method will be good If you have a lot of images with heavy size. Actually I used it when i had 20 images in my app.