# Efficient loading drawable images in android application

Tags: android, memory-management, image-loading

I'm currently working on an application in college. I have created several games incorporating lots of images. My lecturer however is not happy with the app loading the images from the drawable folder, he wants something more efficient on memory.

Just wondering if anyone knows any solution? i looked at lazyloader and asychronous loading but most examples use images from the web. I need an efficient way to load lots of high quality images from drawable folder to UI.

Comment: visite my answer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19001499/increasing-performance-when-loading-images-from-drawable/19001621#19001621)

Comment: Is this in C/C++ or in Java? As you are saying you are making games, but we dont know if you are using something like cocos2dx or w.e.

Comment: Java. Im creating java based games. These are simply games like quizes and math based games. The problem is my quiz game loads images each level for the user to see and select an answer. My lecturer wants a more efficient way to load images compared to loading from drawable folder. Games created in eclipse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your options:

1. Load images from drawable as is now
2. Reduce images size and use lower quality JPEG for mobile
3. Create download class and download images from server to SD card and use it from there

If you using images in your app, you can read them from drawable, SD card or online. The image have to be somewhere to load it.